# nginx subdomain config resolves index.php ok but redirecting other files to server ip

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress

This configuration resolves correctly `/` or `/favicon.ico` but other paths are being redirected to `http://54.236.189.131/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.3`

And actually I'm not sure why is resolving the ip server.

This config is the only one I have under sites-enabled. And the DNS recors seems ok I think.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.tusjuegos.io;

    index index.php;
    root /home/ubuntu/tusjuegos/wordpress/;

    access_log /home/ubuntu/tusjuegos/access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/tusjuegos/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }    

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some terminology: *redirect* in HTTP terms means a `301` or `302` response with a new URL. This causes the browser to automatically load the new URL.

This is not your case: the wrong URL's are in the generated HTML. So the culprit is the software generating your page, in your case **WordPress**. Every web application needs to know in one way or another what's the name of the site.

You need to [properly configure WordPress's site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/).